# Problems with the server connection MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I am a beginner in MongoDB and MAC OS X. I have a web based project using Node.Js-JadeExpress-MongoDB.

After 3 weeks, finally I can integrated JadeExpress and Node.js via terminal, but the problems still come with MongoDB server. Each time i want to connecting a MongoDB server via terminal, i have to create a file bashrc by vim editor.

Inside that, I have to put this code :`export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH .`

I use this tutorial as a reference: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Does anyone know what I have to do to connecting to the MongoDB server efficiently?

Comment: Each time? Is the `~/.bashrc` not saved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not very familiar with command line interface then I would say just take all the mongodb binaries from the `mongodb/bin/` folder and put them in `/usr/bin/` folder. So that you don't have to modify PATH at all.

Not the most efficient way but will solve your problem.